# Setting custom UINavigationBar images for left and right buttons

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, button, uinavigationbar

This is what I have on my storyboard:
[image]

And I wanna change both buttons images. I have a 13x46 image but I'm having problems using it as the button's images. I've searched around for some code but I wasn't very successful with them.
Any ideas?

Comment: This and more: UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.png"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height);
    [backButton setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushBackButton:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] ;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;

Comment: is the image added to your bundle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty simple stuff, just alloc/initWithImage a couple of bar button items, then apply them.

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(someMethod)];
UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(someMethod)];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:leftItem];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:rightItem];
```

This of course assumes that you are actually using a navigation controller. If you just have a navigation bar that you dragged and dropped in interface builder, then you need to make an IBOutlet for the navbar, link it up and then use something like this:

```
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
[item setRightBarButtonItem:rightItem];
[myNavBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
```

You may need to add a flexible space in between.

Comment: tried that, but I get this error now: `-[UIBarButtonItem setNavigationBar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...`

Comment: Yes, the button is added now. But, the thing is, the image is not correctly aligned. i have this image: http://i47.tinypic.com/14mx5i0.png and here's the outcome: http://i46.tinypic.com/2u79bpw.png . What can I do for the image to get into the regular shape?